# In JetBrains Rider, is there keyboard shortcut to add a new class file?

Tags: rider

In JetBrains Rider, is there keyboard shortcut to add a new class file? Perhaps with the same popup to name the C# class, then to save in the currently selected/open directory.

Would save many mouse clicks :-)

Answer (score 12):

To generate new class file in Rider:

##### Method 1

1. In the [**Solution Explorer**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Project_Tool_Window.html?keymap=primary_intellij), select a node.
2. Press <kbd>Alt+Insert</kbd> | <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd> | <kbd>⌘ N</kbd>.
3. Choose **Class/Interface** in the context menu.

[Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Project_Tool_Window.html?keymap=primary_intellij#content_pane_context_menu)

[image: Screenshot]

##### Method 2

1. In the [**Code Editor**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Working_in_the_Editor.html?keymap=primary_intellij), press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Insert</kbd> | <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd> | <kbd>⌃ ⌥ N</kbd>.
2. Choose **Class/Interface** in the context menu.

This will add the new file in the same folder as the current file.

[Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Templates__Applying_Templates__Creating_Files_from_Templates.html?keymap=primary_intellij)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Following your reference, it seems the shortcut for adding a class from inside the editor is now Ctrl+Shift+A. This worked for me. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @anaotha I updated the answer to include the shortcut for the Visual Studio 2022 (Windows) keymap scheme.

Answer (score 5):

There is no dedicated shortcut for a new class, but you can select a node in the Solution Explorer, press `Alt+Insert`, and then pick the desired template from the popup.